# When I Render An Image In Blender My UV Texture Shows Up White

Tags: blender

I Am Making A Model In Blender And This Is How It Turns Out (Not Rendered)

[image]

And When I Render It I Get This

[image]

Im Using `Blender 2.72b`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for http://blender.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is not about programming and is **off topic** as described in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using blender render or cycles render:
if you are using blender render then you need to :

```
1. uv unwrap the object

2. give your object a material
```

[image]

```
3. and finally give that material a texture(texture the image which you are          using)

   3.1: Change the texture type from none to Image or movie
```

[image]

```
   3.2: open the image you want as texture
```

[image]

```
   3.3: change texture coordinates from generated to uv and select the uv map of your object
```

[image]

or if you are using cyceles render then:
    1. uv unwrap the object
    2. give your object a material(ex diffuse shader)
    3. and then in the node editor add in a image texture choose your image and then connect its output to the color input of the shader(ex : diffuse shader)
like the one shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer But I Have Done That And Repeated Your Exact Steps. The Cube, Torus And Cone Textures Seem To Mess Up. And I Am Using Blender Render

Comment: is the texture showing up in texture mode

Comment: i updated the answer for blender render

Comment: thankyou. after doing this like 5 times it worked.

Comment: happy to help. Good to mnow that it works

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center) before attempting to answer more questions. **Do not answer blatantly off-topic questions!**

Comment: as beginner and i dont want to learn or go deep in 3d art i couldn't find working solution for cycles render i spent 3 hours trying different solutions and nothing worked most of the answers in the internet are very old and none of them worked but this one worked great for me thanks lot